# How to append two dataframes in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with an adult dataset where I split the dataframe to label encode categorical columns. Now I want to append the new dataframe with the original dataframe. What is the simplest way to perform the same?

Original Dataframe-

| age | salary |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | 3000 |
| 25 | 2300 |

After label encoding few columns

| country | gender |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

I want to append the above dataframe and the final result should be the following.

| age | salary | country | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | 3000 | 1 | 1 |
| 25 | 2300 | 4 | 2 |

Any insights are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets consider two dataframe named as `df1` and `df2` hence,

```
df1.merge(df2,left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe find your solution in checking [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[32,3000],[25,2300]]), columns=['age', 'salary'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1],[4,2]]), columns=['country', 'gender'])

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

```
         age  salary  country   gender
    0     32      25        1        1
    1   3000    2300        4        2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) if the datrframes rows are matched by index, as follows:

[`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) is a left join by default and ***join by index*** by default.

```
df1.join(df2)
```

In addition to simple syntax, it has the extra advantage that when you put your master/original dataframe on the left, *left join* ensures that the dataframe indexes of the master are retained in the result.

**Result:**

```
   age  salary  country  gender
0   32    3000        1       1
1   25    2300        4       2
```